# java multi-threaded jms queue receiver

Tags: java, multithreading, jms

I am using oracle Advanced Queuing (AQ JMS). I am trying to use multiple threads to consume jms queue using QueueReceiver.

**Question**: This model forks multiple threads, but performance is still close to single threaded model. How to increase queue consumption?

Following is code snipet:

```
final QueueReceiver queueReceiver = getQueueReceiver(queueSession);
        qConn.start();
        //THREAD POOL SIZE
        final int threadPoolSize = getThreadCount();


        final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);

        for (int i = 0; i < threadPoolSize; i++) {
            executor.submit(new MessageWorker(queueReceiver));
        }
```

And message worker code looks like following:

```
    class MessageWorker extends Thread {
    MessageConsumer messageConsumer;

    public MessageWorker(MessageConsumer subs) {
        this.messageConsumer = subs;
    }

    /**
     * @see java.lang.Thread#run()
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Message msg = messageConsumer.receive();
                    if (null != msg) {
                        //log message
                        logMessage(msg);
                        //handle message
                        handleMessage(msg);
                        //ack
                        msg.acknowledge();
                    }
                } catch (JMSException e) {
                    log.error(e);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e);
        } finally {
            log.info("Thread:" + this.getName() + " terminated.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a separate JMS Session for each Thread. It doesn't seem like there is a session created for each Thread in your code snippet.

Comment: (MessageConsumer is created using a Session instance.)

Comment: I have modified code so that each worker create own connection, session and receiver, and have no effect.

Comment: There is no need to create a separate connection. Otherwise it should work with with multiple cores, I believe.

Comment: Is the producer really producing fast enough to see a difference?

Comment: queue is populated from database triggers, i am testing when queue gets @100 messages waiting in queue. BTW, creating session from worker and passing queue connection to worker does not have any effect either :(

Comment: Okay. One more thing I would look into, if the producer does not hang thanks to acknowledging messages.

Comment: good point...i will try that...i think queue receiver is set for auto-acknowledge, then message does not have call ack...?

Comment: And make it a topic instead of a queue.

Comment: that is last option left.... issue there is messages does not get wiped out upon read...

Comment: I get it. Running out of ideas. may be a bottleneck in some other place. I'll try to think about it.

Comment: Just one more idea, sorry if this gets too overwhelming, try yielding or sleeping the thread at each cycle.

Comment: speed is better with Topic instead of Queue, but still not great, you were right that acknowledging process kills performance. I end up adding background job to wipeout processed messages from topic....